# adding a vertical scrollbar for a WinForm panel

Tags: c#, winforms

I am designing a touch optimized WinForm application. The problem is: how to add a custom `VScrollBar` that I can affect its width?

This is my `VScrollBar` code

```
    panel1.VerticalScroll.Value = vScrollBar1.Value;
```

The problem is that it is not scrolling the panel to the end.

Comment: Your statement of "that I can affect its width" is unclear. It could have multiple interpretations.  That statement is implying that you want to change the width of the vertical scrollbar? Yet your code implies that you are wanting to change to where your panel is scrolled.  What is your real issue/desire?

Comment: Potential duplicate: [C# UserControl.VerticalScroll.Value not being set](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/757408/c-sharp-usercontrol-verticalscroll-value-not-being-set).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add a FlowLayoutPanel and set the following property to that:

```
 flowLayoutPanel1.FlowDirection = System.Windows.Forms.FlowDirection.TopDown;
 flowLayoutPanel1.WrapContents = false;
 flowLayoutPanel1.Dock = System.Windows.Forms.DockStyle.Fill;
 flowLayoutPanel1.AutoScroll = true;
```

and you can see the scroll, you can use the Panels and design your application.

Taken from:

[How to make Winform scrollable in C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26010606/how-to-make-winform-scrollable-in-c-sharp)